# Role Based Access Control for different API methods in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am creating REST API for Product, which has following Permission, (create_product, view_product, edit_product). In my Project I am having various users with different roles (Ex: Producer, Retailer, Consumer,...etc). I am assigning permission to individual Roles. I am using Django Group Permission

Example: The "Producer" role has "create_product" and "view_product" permission. The "Retailer" role has "edit_product" permission. The "Consumer" role has no permission.

I want to restrict the Access based on the permission code. I need a generic approach to solve this. I want to use the same approach for different views with different permission codes.

In my view.py,

```
class Product(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

     serializer_class = ProductSerializer
     queryset = Product.objects.all()
```

In settings.py, I have added following code.

```
 REST_FRAMEWORK = {
     'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
           'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
     ),
     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
           'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
           'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
           'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
     ),
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use django group permissions

Comment: yes i am using only Django group permission

Comment: then you could jsut use permissions = ( ( "read_product", "Can read product" ),) in models class meta

Comment: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#proxy-models

Comment: I did the same thing, but I dont know how to use this with Django REST Framework

Comment: you could use rest_framework.permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions in default permissions

Comment: DjangoObjectPermission will only for individual object level. I want individual method level permission in class based view